# jquery function working on jsfiddle but not on my site in cakephp

Tags: jquery, input, html-select, cakephp-2.2

I have got stuck in a dump issue but am not able to work it out , 
I have a range selection of age through two select input buttons.  I took the code from the mark up and it works on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhijatyatewari/VBrEj/10/) but not on the page.

I have tried putting the script on the view file,layout header and at the end of view.

But it never worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some JS error. Track down any error you may be getting using Firebug in Firefox or Chrome Inspector in Google Chrome. Make sure you have included jQuery.js in your cakephp page. Also please note that it's not supported in all the [browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number), so you can use [Polyfill](https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill) if there is any browser specific issue.

**Updates:**

Lets try another approach, instead of getting the value of first input on clicking the second one, What if we try to set a value for second input on changing the first one.

```
$("input#range1").bind('change',function(){
   $("input#range2").val(this.value);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VBrEj/12/

Comment: i have checked Jquery is included in the default layout.but i even checked in the chrome devloper tool, n its there.
I don't have any idea of tracking JavaScript in inspector or on Firebug. Can u give any link . it will be a great help!!

Comment: Just open your page in Google Chrome and press F12 once it is loaded.  The panel will popup at the bottom of the page. Click the last tab named `Console`, and refresh your page again. You should see errors in red.

Comment: thanks!! what i meant was I am not able to interpret/or use console in developers tools Its giving error"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".Now i can't understand which part of the page is giving error as it shows no details.I have checked Jquery is included in the default layout.but i even checked in the chrome devloper tool, n its there. My fields are already number fields with increment/decrements buttons , so i guess pollyfill( IMHO & as far as i know), won't help too.

Comment: So i assume that you have got some syntax error in the console. The best thing you can do is to press `CTRL+u` on your page to copy the source code and put it on jsfiddle.net. Finally share the link for me to figure out the problem.

Comment: my working fiddle with that specific HTML code is already included in the Questions. However this is the link for for [source code](http://jsfiddle.net/abhijatyatewari/VBrEj/11/)

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working fine. What exactly are you trying to do? You JS code seems confusing... you are tracking the click event of `range2` and putting `range1`'s value into it. If this is the case then why do you need `range2` as a spinner box?

Comment: suppose a person wants a range from 35 to 45, where minimum vale set for both the boxes is 15(i kept it equal ,in case a person wants only that particular number as range .i want that the next range should start from the first range , than starting from minimum value i.e. if a person selects 35 in upper input, he should start from 35 and increase if desired in second input ,than starting again from 15 as we know value has to be equal or greater than first one.

Comment: what does not work when you put that code into your page and view it in a browser?

Comment: well, the second spinner-box , doesn't takes the value from the first . and starts with minimum value i.e. is 15. Have included jquery same version as in the fiddle. Jquery library and the script both shows in the source code. Every thing is fine as it should be , but still it doesn't works.

Comment: @DiabloGeto: I've updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you or not?

Comment: yeah its working however i wanted the value to be equal on click to second input, even if a user clicks on the spinner. so i changed 'change' to 'click' [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhijatyatewari/VBrEj/13/) to update the value of the second range simultaneously with first one.